# Clubbing one column values separated by delimiter in Pandas Dataframe based on the groups in another column

Tags: pandas, dictionary, group-by, subset

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:

```
   # df

    colA       colB      

   rqqrs        vqtr            
   MNO          vqtr 
   japl         vqtr
   nsam2        raqm        
   many         3tyua
   3juaik7      3tyua
   janit        yua7us
```

What I am looking to get from this dataframe is to club together the rows of colA which 
have the same values in ColB. For example in the above table the first three rows 
should be clubbed as single row as all the values of ColB are same for these rows.

So the output should like below ( the delimiter can be semicolon or :& etc, in the example below I used :&)

```
# newdf:

   colA                    coLB     

  rqqrs;& MNO;& japl       vqtr
  nsam2                    raqm
  many ;& 3juaik7          3tyua
  janit                    yua7us
```

Honestly, I am not getting much idea as to how to achieve this. I tried grouping the old dataframe by ColB  and then use the ColB unique entries as keys in dictionary and tried to put the ColA entries into values.

However, nothing of that seems to work. If I can get some help, that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `agg` with `join`

```
df.groupby('colB').colA.agg(' ;&'.join)
colB
3tyua         many ;&3juaik7
raqm                   nsam2
vqtr      rqqrs ;&MNO ;&japl
yua7us                 janit
Name: colA, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use use 'groupby' with 'apply(list)'.  The '.unique()' ensures elements are only listed once:

```
df_grouped=df.groupby('colB')['colA'].unique().apply(list)
```